# increase the size of a scale_y_continuous object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm an absolute beginer in `ggplot` but I need 
to rapidly expand the size of the y-labels in a 
code written by a colleague which is currently 
unreachable. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
b1<-cbind(sort(rnorm(100)),1)
b2<-cbind(sort(rnorm(100)),1)
H1 <- data.frame(Direction = c(1:length(b1[,1])),Iind = (b1[,1]), supp = rep("H_1",length(b1[,1])))
H2 <- data.frame(Direction = c(1:length(b1[,1])), Iind = (b2[,1]), supp = rep("H_2",length(b2[,1])))
plotData <- data.frame(rbind(H1, H2))
perfPlot = ggplot(data=plotData, aes(x=Direction, y=Iind, group=supp, colour=supp)) + geom_line(size = 1.2)
perfPlot = perfPlot + scale_y_continuous(name=bquote(paste("I(",H^m,",",bold(.("a")),")")))
perplot
```

I need the size of the complicated y labels (the one `bquote(paste("I(",H^m,",",bold(.("a")),")"))`) to be bigger but I can't find an argument `size` in `scale_y_continuous()`.

Can anyone point me to a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adjusting the `theme()`

```
perfPlot + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=24))
```

[image]